# Set SearchView threshold to zero

Tags: android

I am using `SearchView` in android , i setting an adapter to search view, but suggestion popup box showing after one character, because i set Threshold on 1 ( it is not accept number less than 1 ), how can i set Threshold to Zero?
Like Google please, as you maybe know Google play does not have Threshold on application `SearchView`.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this); 
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String arg0)
{
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(locationSearchAdapater);
}
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"

    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"

    android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"
    android:completionThreshold = "1"  >


</searchable>
```

Comment: You can use autocomplete textview and implement over it and set threshold to 0.

Comment: i cannot override SearchAutoComplete class, because i am getting cast exception when i want to cast from SearchAutoComplete to my custom class, i don't know what should i do , i tested anything,

Comment: Check this may it help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868268/how-to-build-gmail-like-search-box-in-the-action-bar

Answer (score 4):

Use Appcompact activity with v7 Searchview and set threshold as follows,

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(0);
```