# Searching in android with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the library `Material Search Bar` to search my `Firebase Database`, but it doesn't work.

Right here is the layout and it is assumed that when I click on the search bar should give me some suggestions and also to look for products but it is not

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3fzt.png)

My Firebase Database

[Firebase DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btxh6.png)

Here is my Home.java where i put the searchBar

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference product;

TextView userName;

RecyclerView recycler_prod;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product,ProductViewHolder> adapter;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> searchadapter;

MaterialSearchBar searchBar;
String ProductId = "";
List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    product=database.getReference("Product");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    userName= headerView.findViewById(R.id.idUserName);
    userName.setText(Common.currentuser.getName());

    recycler_prod = findViewById(R.id.recycler_card);
    recycler_prod.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_prod.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadProducts();

    searchBar =  findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    searchBar.setPlaceHolder("Productos");
    loadSuggest();
    searchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
    searchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
    searchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String search : suggestList) {
                if (search.toLowerCase().contains(searchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                    suggest.add(search);
            }
            searchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    searchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
            if (!enabled)
                recycler_prod.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
            startSearch(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

        }
    });




}

private void startSearch(CharSequence text) {
    searchadapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(
            Product.class,
            R.layout.card_item,
            ProductViewHolder.class,
            product.orderByChild("Name").equalTo(text.toString())
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, Product model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtProductName.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageProductView);
            final Product local = model;

            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Intent details = new Intent(Home.this, ProductDetail.class);
                    details.putExtra("ProductId", searchadapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(details);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    recycler_prod.setAdapter(searchadapter);
}

private void loadSuggest() {
    product.orderByChild("ProductId").equalTo(ProductId)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Product item = postSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                        suggestList.add(item.getName());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


}

private void loadProducts() {
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(Product.class,
            R.layout.card_item,
            ProductViewHolder.class,
            product) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, Product model, int position) {
            holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getName());
            holder.txtProductDesc.setText(model.getDescription());
            holder.txtProductPrice.setText("$" + model.getPrice());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage())
                    .into(holder.imageProductView);
            final Product clickItem = model;
            holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Intent details = new Intent(Home.this, ProductDetail.class);
                    details.putExtra("ProductId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(details);
                }
            });
        }

    };
    recycler_prod.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_search) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
        Intent mapa = new Intent(Home.this,Maps.class);
        startActivity(mapa);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

My Product.java Model

```
public class Product {
private String Description, Name, Image,Price,Link;

public Product() {
}

public Product(String description, String name, String image, String price, String link) {
    Description = description;
    Name = name;
    Image = image;
    Price = price;
    Link = link;
}

public String getLink() {
    return Link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    Link = link;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    Price = price;
}
 }
```

My ProductViewHolder.java

```
public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView txtProductName,txtProductDesc,txtProductPrice;
public ImageView imageProductView;
private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    txtProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtProductDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    txtProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    imageProductView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
}
 }
```

Thank you for your attention

Comment: i think you get help from this link. It will filter your database items and give you suggestions when you click on searchbar https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/ one more...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369246/implementing-searchview-as-per-the-material-design-guidelines

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682046/applying-word-stemming-in-searchview-for-fetch-data-from-firebase-database)** out.

Answer (score 0):

In your startSearch method, replace your `.equalto` with `.startAt`. See if it works