# Xamarin Android: What is the equivalent code from Java to C#: resource.getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;

Tags: android, xamarin, android-layout-direction

I'm trying to get the layout direction in Xamarin Android from this java code:

```
resource.getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

I tried to make this code:

```
Android.Util.LayoutDirection.Rtl == Android.Views.LayoutDirection.Rtl;
```

But it doesn't Work. I get the error:
[image]

I'm tryin to implement this code in xamarin Android (**from shnizlon's answer**):

[Implementing SearchView as per the material design guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369246/implementing-searchview-as-per-the-material-design-guidelines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if (this.Resources.Configuration.LayoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Rtl)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the shnizlon's answer, I used the `context` variable and the `Android.Content.Res.Resources` namespace for the input variable of the `isRtl` method.

In Java:

```
private boolean isRtl(Resources resources) {
    return resources.getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
}
```

In C# (Xamarin Android):

```
private bool isRtl(Android.Content.Res.Resources resources)
{
     return resources.Configuration.LayoutDirection == Android.Views.LayoutDirection.Rtl;
}
```