# Show dropdown when onQueryTextChange

Tags: android, searchview

I have added a `searchView` in my toolbar and I would like to show a dropdown as android does with the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

So basically I want to display a list of result and change it while the user is typing. I have added already a function to filter my results, but I have no clue how to show the dropdown in the list using my searchView.

Take a look the code below:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_subs, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //TODO: Implement dropdown 
                _list = _repository.filterItems(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

NOTE: something like in the image, I want to show my results(list of strings) in the dropdown.

[image]

any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: just use `setSuggestionsAdapter`, no need for any `OnQueryTextListener`

Comment: @pskink how can I implement it? I have no idea.

Comment: just call `setSuggestionsAdapter` with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Answer (score 0):

you should add this code in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
    SearchAutoComplete autoCompleteTextView = (SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);

if (autoCompleteTextView != null) { 
    autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_search_dropdown_light);
}
```

For more information check this link

[How to build Gmail like search box in the action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868268/how-to-build-gmail-like-search-box-in-the-action-bar)